# Comparing multiple items measured with ordinal scale

Tags: ordinal-data, friedman-test, differences

I have 20 items measured with 7 point ordinal scale by roughly 200 of respondents such that every item's relative importance was assessed by every respondent.

Item example: 
What is the importance of personal integrity for project succes ?

Possible answers: absolutely no importance (1) - minimum importance (2) - rather minor importance (3) - moderately important (4) - quite important (5) - very important (6) - critically important (7)

There is no assumption about equidistance of the scale. Perception of distances vary by respondent, and is very individual. Let's say the scale is truly ordinal.

I need to identify:

1. The differences of measured importance for every item to identify items valued lower and higher than others.
2. The subset of items that are highly valued by more than 80% of respondents.

To find the answer to problem 1 I'm considering two aproaches:

- pairwise sign test (related samples) with signifficancy adjustment. I prefer to use False Discovery Rate (BY) adjustment instead of Family-wise Error Rate (such as Holm or Bonferroni adjustment).
- Friedman's ANOVA (not sure if it doesn't assume equidistance of the scale)

To answer problem 2 I intend to :

- Select all items scored higher by neutral position by at least 80% or respondents (this is an arbitrary decision to the some extent). Let's agree for the moment it is 4 items.
- Compare each of the selected 4 items with all others (4x16 comparisons) using a sign test with signifficancy adjustment.
- Make my final set by adding every items that were not significantly lower valued by respondents.

As a result, my final set will contain 4 items selected at the beginning and all items that were not significantly different from them.

Do you think these approaches are correct?

Comment: Friedman does not assume equidistance as it is based on ranking.

Comment: Wilcoxon signed-rank test is also based on ranks, but takes into account both sign of rank and rank magnitude.
So, can we say that Friedman's ANOVA is an extension of Sign Test for multiple items?

Comment: For illustrative purpose give  an item and its response scale.

Comment: Item: 
What is the importance of personal integrity for project succes ?

possible answers: 

absolutely no importance (1) - minimum importance (2) - rather minor importance (3) - moderately important (4) - quite important (5) - very important (6) - critically important (7)